# how to center navigation bar items?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I'm new at HTML & CSS coding and I have problems trying to center the items in my navigation bar. I've tried many things to center the items but I can't find a solution. I think it has something to do with the `border-style: solid;` of the `.l-triangle-bottom` and `.l-triangle-top` in the CSS (Code below) because when I remove it, all items move to the left.

Can someone please help me out?

Here is my code and some explanations.

**HTML**

```
<div id="navigation_container">
   <div class="l-triangle-top"></div>
      <div class="l-triangle-bottom"></div>
         <div class="rectangle">
            <ul id="navigation">
               <li class="active"><a href="#">&#10029; Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Our History</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Gifts</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Promotion</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="r-triangle-top"></div>
         <div class="r-triangle-bottom"></div>              
      </div>
```

**CSS**

I have a main container with fixed position en center at the top of the page.

```
#navigation_container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 10%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -500px;
}
```

Then I have a rectang in the main container that's were the items are located.

```
.rectangle {
    background: #e5592e;
    height: 62px; 
    position: relative;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);

   -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;

    z-index: 500; 
    margin: 3em 0;
    text-align: center;

}
```

And those are the items.

```
#navigation li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0.1em 0.8em;

}

#navigation li a {
    text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f0f0f0;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    line-height: 60px;

}


#navigation li.active a:hover, #navigation li a:hover {
    margin-top: 2px;
    color: aqua;
}
```

And I have some triangles at each site of the rectangle to make the effect of tape.

```
    .l-triangle-top {
    border-color: #d9542b transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width:50px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 52px;
    left: -50px;

}

.l-triangle-bottom {
    border-color: transparent transparent #d9542b;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:50px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 10px;
    left: -150px;
}


.r-triangle-top {
    border-color: #d9542b transparent transparent;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:50px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: -45px;
    top: -107px;
}

.r-triangle-bottom {
    border-color: transparent transparent #d9542b;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:50px;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: -149px;
    right: -145px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: icons was not centered due to the triangle, so you have to make these **absolute**.

I have also made some changes in html

```css
#navigation_container {
   position: fixed;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 200px;
   top: 0;
   left: 50%;
   margin-top: 00px;
   margin-left: -500px;
  }
  .rectangle {
   /*background: #e5592e;*/
   height: 62px; 
   position: relative;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.55);

   -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
   border-radius: 2px;

   z-index: 500; 
   margin: 3em 0;
   text-align: center;

  }

  #navigation li {
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;;
   margin: 0.1em 0.8em;
  }

  #navigation {
   padding-left: 0;
   position: relative;
   z-index: 2;
   background: #e5592e;
  }

  #navigation li a {
   text-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
   display: block;
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #f0f0f0;
   font-size: 1.6em;
   line-height: 60px;

  }


  #navigation li.active a:hover, #navigation li a:hover {
   top: 2px;
            position: relative;
   color: aqua;
  }

  .l-triangle-top {
   border-color: #d9542b transparent transparent;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width:50px;
   height:0px;
   width:0px;
   position: absolute;
   float: left;
   top: 4px;
   left: -50px;

  }

  .l-triangle-bottom {
   border-color: transparent transparent #d9542b;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:50px;
   height:0px;
   width:0px;
   position: absolute;
   float: left;
   top: -37px;
   left: -49px;
  }


  .r-triangle-top {
   border-color: #d9542b transparent transparent;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:50px;
   height:0px;
   width:0px;
   position: absolute;
   float: right;
   right: -50px;
   top: 0;
  }

  .r-triangle-bottom {
   border-color: transparent transparent #d9542b;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:50px;
   height:0px;
   width:0px;
   position: absolute;
   float: right;
   top: -37px;
   right: -50px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="navigation_container">
  <div class="rectangle">
   <div class="l-triangle-top"></div>
   <div class="l-triangle-bottom"></div>
   <ul id="navigation">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">&#10029; Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our History</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Promotion</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="r-triangle-top"></div>
   <div class="r-triangle-bottom"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track by having this in your CSS which should center them:

`.rectangle {
  text-align: center;
}`

However, you are overriding that style by floating the items left with this code:

`#navigation li {
    float: left;
}`

So, if you delete the `float: left;` style, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal Center Navigation Bar

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  background: #757575;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  margin: 0 0 30px;
}

#nav {
  height: 3.2em;
  width: 760px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}

#nav li {
  float: left;
}

#nav a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
  height: 3.2em;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 3.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: -2px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-left: 2px solid #000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}

#nav a:hover,
#nav a:focus {
  background: #5E9BD9;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CAPABILITIES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">RFQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```